# Bootstrap Pill with Dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set up the Pill with Dropdown UI element from Bootstrap, and it's not showing the dropdown when I click on the caret.  I've looked through the Bootstrap documentation, and its source) and not found what I'm missing.

Do I need to write custom JS to get it to show up?  The docs made it appear that I didn't, that it should just work.

Here's the JS I've included....

```
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here's the HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="dropdown all-camera-dropdown">
           <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            All Cameras
               <b class="caret"></b>
           </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li data-filter-camera-type="all"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">All Cameras</a></li>
            <li data-filter-camera-type="Alpha"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Alpha</a></li>
            <li data-filter-camera-type="Zed"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Zed</a></li>
            <li data-filter-camera-type="Bravo"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Bravo</a></li>

     </ul>
</li></ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you're loading the same plugin multiple times, remove the following scripts from your inclusions and it should work fine:

**Remove**

```
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The `bootstrap.js` script file comes packaged with all of the plugins so you don't need to load the individual script files again.

**KEEP**

```
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: No, while that was insightful and needed to be fixed, it wasn't the error in the code.

Comment: @bluedevil2k that is the most common issue with the dropdowns, so there must be something else at play here. Your markup works fine with the setup i posted above: http://jsfiddle.net/cKBLz/

Comment: I fixed it - the problem was a little deeper than you outlined above.  You were right, I had one error by not including that file.  But, after I loaded it, I ran into a name collision with the bootstrap gem, which caused the bootstrap.js to load as blank.  By removing the gem (or changing the file name), the file loaded correctly, and all the behavior worked as it should.